# Push a one-dimensional array into a 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

How do I push a 1-dimensional array into a 2-dimensional array?

When I use either:

```
phData.push(ehRow);
phData.push([ehRow]);
```

all I get is the last ehRow replicated 1000 times after exiting the for loop. If I hard code the 26 elements of ehRow as arguments to the push, I get what I want, but surely there's a better way.

Comment: That second option is correct! If you can share the rest of your for loop, I'm happy to help you debug.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve] that defines what ehrow is.

Comment: Downvote and vote to close from me, since there is no any response from the askers.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess:

```js
var array = ['a','b','c']
var array_2d = array.map(x => [x])

console.log(array_2d); // --> [['a'],['b'],['c']]

var another_2d_array = [['d'], ['e'], ['f']]
var final_2d_array = [...another_2d_array, ...array_2d]

console.log(final_2d_array); // --> [['d'],['e'],['f'],['a'],['b'],['c']]
```